# Using QTip and calling it

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I am trying to implement the qtip tooltip in my file, but can't figure it out.

here is my code -

```
(<a href="#" onclick="qtip()">?</a>)

<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$('ul:last li.active').qtip({
   content: 'This is an active list element',
   show: 'mouseover',
   hide: 'mouseout'
})
</script>
</body>
```

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: If you figured it out, might the answer be helpful to post for future people who have the same issue?

Comment: sure...it was only that I was using the wrong selector.

Comment: It's recommended to answer your own question and then mark it as answered.

Comment: add a class to a href and call the class instead of ui

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" id="OBJ">?</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){

      $('#OBJ').each(function(){
  $(this).qtip({
 content: 'Some basic content for the tooltip' 
});
}); });
```